# Are there any good ways to see the universal cover of $GL^{+}(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: lie-groups

Are there any good ways to see the universal cover of $GL^{+}(2,\mathbb{R})$? Here $GL^{+}(2,\mathbb{R})$ stands for the identity component of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$, i.e. positive determinant matrices. I am looking for an explicit description of $GL^{+}(2,\mathbb{R})$. Thanks.

Comment: As a space or as a group?

Comment: Excuse for my low level question: do we have a good definition of universal covers of Lie groups other than viewing them as subsets of $R^{n^{2}}$ and using the inherit topology? Do you imply we can put a different topology by viewing them abstractly as topological groups? (and thus can have different universal covers).

Comment: Yes, as a group. I think that the universal cover, whatever the construction, is automatically group.

Comment: @user32240, it is not true that the universal covering of every Lie group is a Lie group of matrices: the standard example is $SL(2,\mathbb R)$, whose universal cover is not a linear group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I see. For unknown reason someone revived this thread, thank you.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I am reading Jim Belk's proof on the other thread, but since $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{R}^{2}$, its universal cover should be $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Can't I embedd it into $M_{3,3}$ via the diagonal mapping?

Comment: That embdding will not give you an embedding of groups. Every manifold can be embedded in some way in a space of matrices, that follows from Whitney's embedding theorems; but here we have the group structure to take care of too.

Answer (score 5):

This is borrowed from Clifford Taubes's *differential geometry*:

The group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{R}^{2}$. This can be seen by using a linear change of coordinates on $M(2,\mathbb{R})$ that writes the entires in terms of $(x,y,u,v)$ as follows $$M_{1,1}=x-u, M_{22}=x+u,M_{12}=v-y,M_{21}=v+y$$
The condition $\det(M)=1$ now says that $x^{2}+y^{2}=1+u^{2}+v^{2}$. This understood, the diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ sends a triple $(\theta,a,b)$ to the matrix determined by $$x=(1+a^{2}+b^{2})^{1/2}\cos[\theta],y=(1+a^{2}+b^{2})^{1/2}\sin[\theta],u=a,v=b$$ Here $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ is the angular coordinate for $\mathbb{S}^{1}$.

And it should not be difficult for you to see the universal cover of this space is $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

The typo in the solution was corrected by Taubes' email.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't quite understand why you construct the universal cover of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. How are $GL^{+}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ related?

Comment: You can homotopically deform $GL^{+}(2,\mathbb{R})$ into $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ by scaling the determinant. So they should be homotopically equivalent. Therefore knowing the universal cover of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is enough.

Comment: I do not understand the diffeomorphism: the determinant of the matrix will be zero!

Comment: I suspect you did not understand we translated $det(M)=1$ to the other condition.

Comment: But the other condition then reads $1 + a^2 + b^2 = a^2 + b^2$, doesn't it?

Comment: You are right. I suspect Taubes made a mistake here. But I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: I emailed Taubes, just in case we am wrong.

Comment: Now corrected, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately the diffeomorphism $\operatorname{Sl}(2, \mathbb{R}) \approx S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ is not a homomorphism of groups, $\operatorname{Sl}(2, \mathbb{R})$ is not abelian.